# Not sure how to use CodePen code on ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I want to use this as a background for one of my pages: https://codepen.io/arickle/pen/XKjMZY I have no clue how to go about this. I have tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work. .................................

```
<body class="back-row-toggle splat-toggle">
  <div class="rain front-row"></div>
  <div class="rain back-row"></div>
  <div class="toggles">
    <div class="splat-toggle toggle active">SPLAT</div>
    <div class="back-row-toggle toggle active">BACK<br>ROW</div>
    <div class="single-toggle toggle">SINGLE</div>
  </div>
</body>

var makeItRain = function() {
  //clear out everything
  $('.rain').empty();

  var increment = 0;
  var drops = "";
  var backDrops = "";

  while (increment < 100) {
    //couple random numbers to use for various randomizations
    //random number between 98 and 1
    var randoHundo = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (98 - 1 + 1) + 1));
    //random number between 5 and 2
    var randoFiver = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1) + 2));
    //increment
    increment += randoFiver;
    //add in a new raindrop with various randomizations to certain CSS properties
    drops += '<div class="drop" style="left: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
    backDrops += '<div class="drop" style="right: ' + increment + '%; bottom: ' + (randoFiver + randoFiver - 1 + 100) + '%; animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"><div class="stem" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div><div class="splat" style="animation-delay: 0.' + randoHundo + 's; animation-duration: 0.5' + randoHundo + 's;"></div></div>';
  }

  $('.rain.front-row').append(drops);
  $('.rain.back-row').append(backDrops);
}

$('.splat-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('splat-toggle');
  $('.splat-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});

$('.back-row-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('back-row-toggle');
  $('.back-row-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});

$('.single-toggle.toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('body').toggleClass('single-toggle');
  $('.single-toggle.toggle').toggleClass('active');
  makeItRain();
});
```

makeItRain();

Comment: first, convert all "class" words to "className"

Comment: Then, you need to use jQuery library because this code is not pure JavaScript. So, you should import it as a cdn in your "index.html" file or install it using npm.